# Opencart 3.x Cache-Control with $this->request->get

Tags: php, sass, opencart, dashboard, scss-mixins

Using Opencart 3.0.3.2
I have developed a module which displays a list of products in the admin section of Opencart. 
Each product has a button next to it - The button action is as follows:

```
https://example.com/admin/index.php?route=extension/shipping/mymodule&user_token=W0nBWaeKPjpeHFSMb4QmCqmt3sW7hA6Z&product_id=422&active_tab=1&addfree
```

addfree is picked up in the controller by checking $this->request->get['addfree'].

**The problem is with caching:**

I have the same module installed in a 2.3.0.2 installation and in a 3.0.3.2 installation. Both have virtually identical .htaccess files.

The 3.x insists on loading my URLs above from disk cache with `Cache-Control: max-age=900` as specified in the .htaccess

```
ExpiresByType text/html                             "access plus 15 minutes"
```

The 2.3.0.2 loads the same URLs with `Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate`

I have no idea why this is happenning.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION:
[As stated in this post by ADD Creative.](https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=202&t=214597&p=768329#p768325)

If you want to keep your .htaccess as is, with a caching timespan for text/html content, but also disable caching from OC 3.x responses & redirects, you can follow the directions in the linked post above.

For myself, as a developer of OC extensions, I have decided to go with option #3 in this post.

So when developing my extensions for OC 3.x I have to remember to :

1. Precede every $this->response->setOutput(...) with :

> ```
> $this->response->addHeader('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'); $this->response->addHeader('Pragma: no-cache');
> ```

2. AND Precede every $this->response->redirect(...) with :

> ```
> header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); header("Pragma: no-cache");
> ```

In this way, I am absolutely sure that anyone using my extension will not see any caching no matter what they have in their .htaccess, and I will not face any support issues on the matter and I will not have to ask them to change anything in order for my extension to work on their system.

That's it!